# making a radio button remain selected on postback

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, webforms

I am using a GridView with its first column as a template field with radio buttons.

I need to make the first radio button in the first row of the grid remain default selected during page load / postback.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this:
http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/adding-a-gridview-column-of-radio-buttons-vb

The heading titled "Using a Literal Control to Inject Radio Button Markup" may be of particular interest to you